# How to deal with a namespace different from the globally set one?

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

namespace: ns1

resources:
  - r1a.yaml
  - r1b.yaml
  - r1c.yaml
  - r1d.yaml
  - r1e.yaml
  - r2.yaml # needs to be placed in namespace ns2
```

Let's assume above situation. The problem is objects specified in `r2.yaml` would be place in `ns1` even if `ns2` is explicitely referenced in `metadata.namespace`.

How do I have to deal with this? Or how can I solve this (as I assume there a multiple options)?

Comment: Not sure if this will be possible as Kustomize is patching all resources with the same value according to template. Could you elaborate your scenario? I will make some tests. It will be some kind of automatization?

Comment: Would you say that my described use case indicates a misuse of kustomize? The scenario is that kustomize has been used to setup Argo and various workflows in namespace argo. Now Argo Events is being introduced and its setup should be embedded into this kustomize configuration but Argo Events needs to be installed into namespace argo-events.

Answer (score 3):

I've looked into this and I came up with one idea.

```
├── base
│   ├── [nginx.yaml]  Deployment nginx ns: default
|   ├── [nginx2.yaml]  Deployment nginx ns: default
|   ├── [nginx3.yaml]  Deployment nginx ns: default
|   ├── [nginx4.yaml]  Deployment nginx ns: default
|   ├── [nginx5.yaml]  Deployment nginx ns: nginx
│   └── [kustomization.yaml]  Kustomization 
└── prod
    ├── [kustomization.yaml]  Kustomization 
    └── [patch.yaml] patching namespace
```

You need to have 2 directories, in this setup are: `base` and `prod`. In `base` directory you should use your base YAMLs and `kustomization.yaml` file. In my scenario I have 6 YAMLs: `nginx/1/2/3/4.yaml` based on [Kubernetes Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/#creating-and-exploring-an-nginx-deployment), and `nginx5.yaml` which looks the same but with additional `spec.namespace: nginx`.

**In `base` directory:**

```
$ cat kustomization.yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- nginx1.yaml
- nginx2.yaml
- nginx3.yaml
- nginx4.yaml
- nginx5.yaml
```

And 5 YAMLs with nginx.

**In `Prod` directory:**

You should have 2 files. `kustomization.yaml` and `patch.yaml`.

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: ns1
bases:
- ../base
patchesJson6902:
- target:
    group: apps
    version: v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: nginx-deployment-5
  path: patch.yaml

$ cat patch.yaml
- op: replace
  path: /metadata/namespace
  value: nginx
```

When you will use `kustomize build .` in `prod` directory, all `nginx-deployment/-2/-3/-4` will be in the `namespace: ns1` and `nginx-deployment-5` will be in `namespace: nginx`.

```
~/prod (project)$ kustomize build .
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-5
  namespace: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.14.2
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: ns1
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.14.2
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-2
  namespace: ns1
spec:
```

**Useful links**:

- [Kustomize Builtin Plugins](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/guides/extending_kustomize/builtins/)
- [Customizong](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/#customizing)
- [Kustomization Patches](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/kustomization/patches/)